# weekly stockchart with python

Tags: python, matplotlib, finance, candlestick-chart

I'm trying to make some weekly stock charts with technical indicators (moving averages, volume moving averages, etc, I currently use ta-lib). I programmed daily charts with matplotlib (code below). I did not manage to generate weekly charts, where 5 ohlc candles are combined to one weekly candle. Your help therefore is highly appreciated.

I am open for alternative solution to matplotlib if they are preferred. However, they should be in python.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.finance as mpf
import numpy as np
ticker = ('AAPL')
start = (2016, 1, 1)
end = (2016, 2, 12)

quotes = np.array(mpf.quotes_historical_yahoo_ohlc(ticker, start, end))

y = np.linspace(90, 105, len(quotes))
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, sharex=True, figsize=(8, 6))
mpf.candlestick_ohlc(ax1, quotes, width=0.6, colorup='g', colordown='r')
ax1.set_title('aapl')
ax1.set_ylabel('index level')
ax1.grid(True)
ax1.xaxis_date()
plt.bar(quotes[:, 0] - 0.25, quotes[:, 5], width=0.5)
ax2.set_ylabel('volume')
ax2.grid(True)
ax2.autoscale_view()
plt.setp(plt.gca().get_xticklabels(), rotation=30)
```

Comment: It's unclear exactly what the issue is.  Could you be more specific than "struggling transforming these into weekly charts"?

Comment: Thanks Tom for your commend. I edited the original post accordingly. please let me know if this is unclear..

Answer (score 0):

Write a function that returns a weekly average of each variable used to plot the candle stick (OHLC). Something along these lines:

```
closePrice = [2.0, 2.3, 2.6, 2.5, 2.2, 2.1, 1.8, 1.9, 2.2, 2.5, 3.7, 3.8, 3.4]

def weeklyFromDaily(values):
    weeklyData = []
    numberOfdays = len(values)
    print('numberOfDays', numberOfdays)
    numberOfWeeks = int(numberOfdays/5)
    print('NumberOfWeeks', numberOfWeeks)
    weekNum = 0
    while weekNum < numberOfWeeks:
        oneWeekAvg = (values[0+(5*weekNum)]+values[1+(5*weekNum)]+values[2+(5*weekNum)]+values[3+(5*weekNum)]+values[4+(5*weekNum)]) / 5.0
        weeklyData.append(oneWeekAvg)
        weekNum += 1

    return weeklyData

x = weeklyFromDaily(closePrice)
print('Weekly Data Set', x)
```